# Расположение точки относительно отрезка

Tags: алгоритм, математика, геометрия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть кривая (верхняя красная), которая задается массивом точек. Точки соединяются отрезками.
Также есть точки, перемещающиеся по плоскости (беленькое месиво). Нужно сделать так, чтобы точки не перемещались за пределы кривой, что они, к сожалению, делают с большой охотой.

```
x -= dx;
y += dy;
for (i = uCoords.x.length - 1; i > 1; i--) {
    if (x >= uCoords.x[i]) 
    {
        if (((x - uCoords.x[i]) * (uCoords.y[i+1] - uCoords.y[i])) / 
                    (uCoords.x[i+1] - uCoords.x[i]) + uCoords.y[i] <= y)
        {
            y -= dy;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

x, y - координаты одной точки, перемещающейся по плоскости, uCoords - кривая

Массив отсортирован от меньшего к большему по координате х, точки появляются со стороны с большей координатой х.
Выражение под if получено из уравнения прямой.

Comment: В смысле ваша "кривая" - *замкнутая* ломаная?

Comment: Нет, разомкнутая. Точки, появляются под ней.

Comment: "Массив отсортирован от меньшего к большему"? От меньшего к большему чего именно?

Comment: Вы что-нибудь знаете о Вашей красной кривой? На рисунке - две красные кривые. О какой из них Вы говорите?

Comment: О верхней! Знаю сто точек, принадлежащих ей.

Comment: Очень хорошо. Можно ли сказать, что эта кривая задает функцию? Т.е. - любому значению `х` соответствует максимум один `у`?

Comment: Да. Каждому uCoords.x[i] соответствует uCoords.y[i]

Comment: Что делает/должен делать этот код? Каков алгоритм перемещения точек?

Comment: Просто каждый момент времени координаты точек изменяются линейно

Answer (score 0):

1.Найти, в какой промежуток попадает белая точка. Для упорядоченных красных в общем случае это можно делать двоичным поиском, а при гарантии, то каждая новая белая не сдвигается влево - простым линейным поиском, начиная с текущего интервала. В приведённом коде, вероятно (мы не знаем о порядке красных точек), проверка идёт справа, и для точек, удалённых от правого края, может быть довольно долгой.

2.Интерполированное значение для y, соответствующего данному x на найденном промежутке, используется верное. Но почему делается поправка `y -= dy;`? Это приводит ординату точки к предыдущему значению, но ведь при изменении абсциссы и красная линия могла стать ниже, поэтому для того, чтобы гарантировать, что белая точка ниже, нужно использовать ограничение интерполированным  значением

```
    yin = ((x - uCoords.x[i]) * (uCoords.y[i+1] - uCoords.y[i])) / 
                (uCoords.x[i+1] - uCoords.x[i]) + uCoords.y[i]
```

как именно ограничивать - зависит от целей. Может быть - присвоить минимум из прошлого значения белой точки и соответствующего абсциссе интерполированного значения красной линии?

```
      y = min (y - dy, yin)
```